# Repeat input by a certain amount of times in python

Tags: python

I am having an issue with getting a inputted list to spit out the sum can you help. Sorry I'm a newbie

```
def adding ():

    a = input("Type the numbers you want to add here")
    b = sum(a)
    print(b)

adding ()
```

Comment: Do you want to repeat the input, or to output the sum, or both?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
>>> a = input("Type the numbers you want to add here: ")
Type the numbers you want to add here: 1 2 3 4 5
>>> b = sum(map(int,a.split()))
>>> b
15
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python *3*, your input function will return a string (a list of characters).  You will need to split this up and convert the bits into numbers to add them.  You can do it like this:

`sum([int(x) for x in a.split()])`.

The square brackets are what is known as a list comprehension (which you can Google if you want to know more).

If you are using Python *2*, you should use `raw_input("Type numbers...")` instead of `input`, and then split/convert (or do what @BhargavRao suggested).

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = raw_input("Enter the Numbers : ")
number_list = map(int, numbers.split())
print sum(number_list)
```

***Output***

```
Enter the Numbers : 8 3 9 0
20
```